# Unable to 'Start Testing' for internal testing with Testflight

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, ios8

I am using xcode version 6.4 due to swift 1.2 
Unable to 'Start Testing' for internal testing. All it shows is an error message with the message "operation_failed"

Has anyone been able to start testing for their Testflight builds ?

[image]

Comment: We have exactly the same problem. Went to 7, had tons of issues. Just tried to roll back to build targeting 6.4 and publish. No luck.

Comment: Me, too. I upload build with 6.4's Organizer and problem occured. I tried to upload with 7.0.1 Organizer and the same result. Now, I'm downloading Xcode7.1.0 and will try.

Comment: Am using swift 1.2 , cannot use xcode 7 :(

Comment: Me, too. I only use Xcode 7~'s Organizer ;)

Comment: Correction our build is made with Xcode 7 and targeting iOS9

Comment: Me too.  Also see this: a) timeout on forums.developer.apple.com, b) When submitting new version for testing the screen acknowledges my mouse click, but returns to submission screen without error message, no apple server outages on https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/, but that is not surprising because it does not list developer servers.

Comment: Happens to hundreds of users. Me too. There's an open bug, let's hope this is resolved soon.

Comment: @KobyDouek Thanks for the update Koby, is there some place we should plug into to monitor this?

Comment: It just got solved for me , it was a bug with itunes connect . I checked this morning and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is finally resolved for us.

We upped the version and resubmitted.

The error only occurred when we tried to activate testing for internal users. skipping that we submitted the build for approval for external testing. When we tried to active it for external testing it went through without error.

Hope that helps!